# htaccess - change file dir with filter

Tags: .htaccess, filter, cpanel

I'm currently trying to make a htaccess thing to find the file in new/ if the request uri not contains api or list. I tried to do a thing like this but, it shows **403** error. Are there a easier way to filter, or?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /list/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/ new/$1 [L, R]
```

Full htaccess code

```
#remove html file extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#remove php file extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

#set max post size
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 3000
php_value max_input_time 6000
php_value post_max_size 800M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

#Caching schema
<FilesMatch "\.(png|svg|css|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400000"
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.html

#Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files error_log>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `new/` directory?

Comment: No i don't have it in new/

Comment: ok can you provide your full .htaccess in question

Comment: @anubhava here you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** With OP's full htaccess file please try following.

```
#remove html file extension
RewriteEngine on 
##For external redirect rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(?:api|list).*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ new/$1 [L,R=301]

##For internal redirect rule.
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)/?$ $1 [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]

#remove php file extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L] 

#set max post size
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 3000
php_value max_input_time 6000
php_value post_max_size 800M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

#Caching schema
<FilesMatch "\.(png|svg|css|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400000"
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.html

#Custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files error_log>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

---

---

With your shown attempts/rules, could you please try following once. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on 
##For external redirect rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:api|list)/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ new/$1 [L,R=301]

##For internal redirect rule.
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)/?$ $1 [L,NC]
```

---

***OR try following rules set:*** Please make sure try only 1 set at a time, either above OR following.

```
RewriteEngine on 
##For external redirect rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(?:api|list).*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ new/$1 [L,R=301]

##For internal redirect rule.
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)/?$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I tried both, but it says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @BenMert, ok, so any other rules have in your htaccess file apart from these?

Comment: Things in my htaccess file: ur code, remove html/php file exension, some php_value things, caching schema, prevent viewing .htaccess and error_log files, custom 404 and preventing dir listing

Comment: @BenMert, ok so is there new directory present in your system? If yes then are your all pages/files present there?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @BenMert, I meant lets say you have path like `/root/new/` and you htaccess is in `/root/` directory. Then do you have index.php your all php files inside new directory?

Comment: I have different folders too, i.e `/root/api/` or  `/root/list` except `/root/new/`, and i'm not using a php file in new directory

Comment: And @RavinderSingh13 i don't have any php files in new directory, php files in other directories like api and list

Comment: @BenMert, oh ok, but how things will be served from backend? You want to show new in URL but want to keep serving files from url which we hit on browser? Like if someone hits `http://localhost:80/api` it should change in browser to `http://localhost:80/new/api`(just an example) and in backend it should serve files from /root/api only? Could you please confirm on same.

Comment: Im trying to let my webhost (cpanel) get the files from `/new/` but the url keeps as `/`. I found the code in a pastebin copy website (u can see it in my question). But still idk how to filter the requests

Comment: @BenMert, could you please try my EDIT htaccess rule file once? Please make sure to clear cache after saving new rules in your htaccess and before testing your URLs, let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: I added `new` to regex, its not giving the error anymore. And I'm trying it in incognito tabs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On 

# redirect to /new if not /api, /list, /new and file exists in /new
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(new|api|list)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new/$0 -f
RewriteRule .* /new/$0 [L,R=301,NE]

## remaining rules go below this line ##

# remove html file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]

# remove php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache or test from a new browser.